# Continuous bijection whose inverse is not continuous at uncountably many points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I am interested in understanding to what extent continuous bijections fail to be homeomorphisms. For example, suppose $X, Y$ are metric spaces and $f: X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection. Is it possible that $f^{-1}$ fails to be continuous at
uncountably many points of $Y$?

Apologies if the question is trivial!

Comment: @Benjamin: The product of uncountably many non-trivial metric spaces is never metrizable: it isn’t even first countable.

Comment: @Brian: Very interesting. What would be a reference to the statement in your comment?

Comment: @Prism: I don’t know any actual reference offhand, but it’s not hard to prove. If there’s a countable local base at a point $p$ of the product, there’s one whose members are basic open sets in the product, and it’s not hard to construct an open nbhd of $p$ that doesn’t contain any of them, so they can’t actually be a local base at $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be the reals with the discrete topology and $Y$ the reals with the usual topology, and let $f$ be the identity map; then $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable, $f$ is a continuous bijection, and $f^{-1}$ is nowhere continuous.

Comment: Knew you would answer it! :) Thanks for the swift answer.

Comment: @Prism: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be $[0,1)$ and Y $s^1$ , f send each point on to interval to 1 sphere f is bijective and countinuous and $f^{-1}$ is'nt countinuous.
By taking the uncounteble product you will get a countinious bijection witch its inverses isnt countinous at uncountable number of points.